# print only array items that are greater than a certain int

Tags: java

I wrote this simple script that reads a text file and then adds the data to an array however i only want to print the first and last name of the students that have over 90 credits

```
Student[] student = new Student[50];

        Scanner userin, filein;
        String filename;
        int numStudents;

        // Get the filename from the user, with exception handling to deal with incorrect file names
        userin = new Scanner(System.in);
        filename = null;
        filein = null;
            filename =  Students.txt;
            try {
                filein = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename)); // try to open the file
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // failed to open the file
                System.out.println("Invalid file - try again");
                filename = null;
            }

numStudents = 0;
        while (filein.hasNext()){
String lastName = filein.next();
String firstName = filein.next();            
double gpa = filein.next();
int Credits = filein.next();

            student[numStudents++] = new Student(lastName,firstName,gpa,Credits);    

        }     

int i=0;  
      do
      {


            System.out.println(student[i].toString());

            i++;


      }
    while ((student[i] != null)&&(i <= student.length));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"script"?

This is some *ugly* code.  Formatting and structure matter.  I'd recommend paying more attention to it in the future.  It'll make your maintenance life easier as your programs (aka "scripts") become more complex.

Learn the [Sun Java coding standards](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).  You aren't following them now.

Everything in Java has to be a part of a class.  I'll assume that you know that.  This must be a snippet you cut out of your class.

Your code is too chaotic to worry about making it nice.  This'll work:

```
   if (student[i].getCredits() >= 90)
       System.out.println(student[i].toString());
```